# Write audio packet to file using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

I am trying to write audio packet to file using ffmpeg. The source device sending the packet after some interval. e.g.

```
First packet has a time stamp 00:00:00 
Second packet has a time stamp 00:00:00.5000000
Third packet has a time stamp 00:00:01
And so on...
```

Means two packet per second.

I want to encode those packets and write to a file.

I am referring the Ffmpeg example from link [Muxing.c](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/muxing_8c-example.html)

While encoding and writing there is no error. But output file has only 2 sec audio duration and speed is also super fast.

The video frames are proper according the settings.

I think the problem is related to calculation of pts, dts and duration of packet.

How should I calculate proper values for pts, dts and duration. Or is this problem related to other thing?

Code:

```cpp
void AudioWriter::WriteAudioChunk(IntPtr chunk, int lenght, TimeSpan timestamp)
{
    int buffer_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, outputStream->tmp_frame->channels, outputStream->tmp_frame->nb_samples,  outputStream->AudioStream->codec->sample_fmt, 0);

    uint8_t *audioData = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(static_cast<void*>(chunk));
    int ret = avcodec_fill_audio_frame(outputStream->tmp_frame,outputStream->Channels, outputStream->AudioStream->codec->sample_fmt, audioData, buffer_size, 1);

    if (!ret)
       throw gcnew System::IO::IOException("A audio file was not opened yet.");

    write_audio_frame(outputStream->FormatContext, outputStream, audioData);
}


static int write_audio_frame(AVFormatContext *oc, AudioWriterData^ ost, uint8_t *audioData)
{
       AVCodecContext *c;
       AVPacket pkt = { 0 };
       int ret;
       int got_packet;
       int dst_nb_samples;

       av_init_packet(&pkt);
       c = ost->AudioStream->codec;

       AVFrame *frame = ost->tmp_frame;

      if (frame)
      {
          dst_nb_samples = av_rescale_rnd(swr_get_delay(ost->swr_ctx, c->sample_rate) + frame->nb_samples, c->sample_rate, c->sample_rate, AV_ROUND_UP);
          if (dst_nb_samples != frame->nb_samples)
            throw gcnew Exception("dst_nb_samples != frame->nb_samples");

          ret = av_frame_make_writable(ost->AudioFrame);
          if (ret < 0)
             throw gcnew Exception("Unable to make writable.");

          ret = swr_convert(ost->swr_ctx, ost->AudioFrame->data, dst_nb_samples, (const uint8_t **)frame->data, frame->nb_samples);
          if (ret < 0) 
            throw gcnew Exception("Unable to convert to destination format.");

          frame = ost->AudioFrame;

          AVRational timebase = { 1, c->sample_rate };
          frame->pts = av_rescale_q(ost->samples_count, timebase, c->time_base);
          ost->samples_count += dst_nb_samples;
      }

      ret = avcodec_encode_audio2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_packet);
      if (ret < 0) 
        throw gcnew Exception("Error encoding audio frame.");

      if (got_packet)
      {
        ret = write_frame(oc, &c->time_base, ost->AudioStream, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
            throw gcnew Exception("Audio is not written.");
      }
      else
         throw gcnew Exception("Audio packet encode failed.");

      return (ost->AudioFrame || got_packet) ? 0 : 1;
}

static int write_frame(AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, const AVRational *time_base, AVStream *st, AVPacket *pkt)
{
    av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, *time_base, st->time_base);
    pkt->stream_index = st->index;
    return av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_ctx, pkt);
}
```

Comment: Either pts/dts calculated incorrectly or one of the timebases is wrong. I suggest adding some debug logs to see pts and timebase of encoded packets right after `avcodec_encode_audio2`, and then again right before av_interleaved_write_frame (there is already log for this place in that example).

Comment: @AndreyTurkin No sir the pts and dts are same. And timebase is also same of AVStream and AVCodecContext i.e. {1,44100}.

Comment: And pts/dts increase by 22050 each frame, right? Also I'm looking at the example code and there is swresample there. Maybe it is configured incorrectly and does this... Can you share your source code which does that?

Comment: @AndreyTurkin No sir pts and dts are increase by 1152. Code sample is added in question. Sorry for late rply.

Comment: `lenght` parameter is not used anywhere - that's the big issue here. You _have_ to consume all the input data. But you also need to get resampled audio in chunks, each exactly the same length as requested by the codec. Ideally you should also use `timestamp` parameter as a source for `pts` (this sometimes allows to handle gaps in audio data), but then you'd need to estimate timestamps for each output chunk, account for resampler delay, fix up small jitters by also counting samples like you do now, etc - that's a bit of a PITA.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin I am using directshow filter as a source. The `length` parameter is coming with the audio chunk raised by the filter. How I can get the resampled audio in chunks. Is there any sample code available.